# Issues with symlink after upload to server

Tags: laravel

Everything works perfect on my local machine, but when I upload it to the server and run the symlink script with

```
<?php

symlink('/home/percunex/ipf/storage/app/public', 
'/home/percunex/public_html/storage');

?>
```

The link to the storage is created but can't be accessed. 
Please how do I resolve this?

Comment: What server do you have on your local machine and what server do you have on the remote machine?

Comment: just print the ls -l in /home/project_directory/public and check where it's pointing

Comment: Hope you have generated sym link using php artisan generate:link

Comment: I have xampp installed on my local machine and namecheap is my remote server

Comment: Yes, I have done that on my local machine, everything looks fine locally....